# ZSH: commands do not support robotframework installation i.e. pip install robotframework command not found

Tags: robotframework, zsh, macos-big-sur

I am Mac User (Big Sur 11.2.3) and I changed the Terminal from bash to zsh. I had a really hard time to install pip and set up the Environment Path and when I came to the point to install robotframework and all the paraphernalia I get a command not found on zsh.
Has someone sorted this out?
**~ % pip install robotframework

zsh: command not found: pip**

Comment: Where is `pip` located in your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Python3 (which is installed on MacOS BigSur) to install *roboframework*?

Check path: `which pyhton3`

PIP-version: `python3 -m pip --version`

You can change shells zhs/bash/... for you install session, if that helps (to follow the roboFW install-guides).

Comment: Yes I use Python3.9.2 but no the "native" Python version in MacOs 11.2.3 is 2.7 not 3. So the best solution is and I did it to change the shell again going back to bash.

Answer (score 0):

`zsh: command not found: pip` means that the dir containing `pip` is not in your `$path`. There's probably something you forgot to copy from your `.bashrc` file to your `.zshrc` file. If you're using [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage your Python versions (and you should!), then this is the line in question:

```sh
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice to have installed the PyEnv.